# connectivity of a matroid equal to its rank?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, matroids

The connectivity $\eta(X)$ of a simplicial complex $X$ is defined as the
$$1+\min_j\{j \mid \tilde{H}_j(X)\neq 0\}$$
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_connectivity) for this definition.)

If $M$ is a matroid not having a co-loop (an element in every independent set of $M$), then $\eta(M)=rank(M)$. (See, for example, Lemma 3.2 [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2006-358-11/S0002-9947-06-03833-5/S0002-9947-06-03833-5.pdf))
Anyone knows a proof of this theorem? I am not able to find a proof in the reference they cite there, and it seems the reference uses some other notation.

I heard that a matroid looks like a wedge sum of spheres. Not sure if it helps.